# react-native run-android not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04, react-native-cli

i have a problem with react native in ubuntu, i have installed,

java jdk 8 `(both javac --version)` as well as `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives the proper output.

I have also installed android studio and set the android environment variables as well as the tools and `echo $ANDROID_HOME` gives output of the sdk location.

I have also installed gradle version 4.4.

I am unable to start the android app using `react-native run-android`. can any one let me know if i have missed something during installation.

And react-native as well as android studio works fine as I am currently using `react-native start` to start the metro builder as well as the other react-native cli commands. also android studio and gradle is also able to generate debug as well as release apks with no problems.

The error i get,

> Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/igate-naveed/Documents/ReactNative/mobile-app-android/node_modules (16ms)
>   Starting JS server...
>   Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
>   Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
>   set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: @Naveen i have updated my code

Comment: check with `adb devices` command whether device is connected or not.

Comment: yah its connected also ran `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` for the bundler

Comment: ....., read the error above for details.  Can you post the error ?

Comment: cd into your android folder and run `./gradlew installDebug --info` or with --stacktrace. it can give you a better output to find the problem

Comment: @Taxellool  hey `./gradlew installDebug --info` gives me permission denied. but `gradle installDebug` successfully installs the app.

Comment: looks like your gradlew file does not have execution permission. try `chmod +x ./gradlew` in your android folder and run `./gradlew installDebug` again

Comment: @Taxellool  i gave `./gradlew` permission it ran successfully

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a project like this:

```
react-native init myProjectName
```

Then, start an emulator from Android Studio... Afterwards:

```
npm install && npm start
```

in your project directory, and from another terminal, inside your project directory, run :

```
react-native run-android
```

Is this working?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the npm install manager, I used yarn and it worked for me. In your project directory, just do:

```
(project-directory)$ yarn
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the gradle version.
2. Create new project:

   ```
   react-native init projectname
   ```
3. Uninstall the npm pack.
4. Reinstall the npm pack again.
5. `npm start`
6. `react-native start`
7. `react-native run-android`